# Single Sign On - Cross Site

Tags: authentication, cross-domain, single-sign-on

I am trying to create a single-sign on which will work cross-sites and to be honest I am getting confused as to how it would work.

Basically what I need to happen is that we have an application which a user can register an account on for this example, www.domain1.com - which we host for our client in ASP.net.

Our client has now requested that from their own system - to which they will have logins at www.domain2.com - once a user logs in then they will be able to transfer over to our hosted system www.domain1.com without having to login again...

The way I understand it is that our Client would either need to check automatically somehow whether the user had registered for an account on www.domain1.com OR they would need the user, when logged into www.domain2.com, specify that they have an account and enter the details required to log in to www.domain1.com - which they would store and then pass over to us when the user was transferred over to www.domain1.com.

Can anyone please shed any light on how to achieve the above, if possible OR point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear Darren Formosa,
Please clarify if you try to create an SSO framework or you try to use SSO in your application using the existing one (and which one).

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569542/same-webserver-same-drupal-same-db-single-sign-on