# Same webserver, same drupal, same db, single sign on?

Tags: php, drupal-7, cross-domain, single-sign-on, session-cookies

I have a webserver with a drupal 7 installed on.
Many primary domains are pointing to this webserver (es domain1.com, domain2.com) and each domain is see the same website.

But if i log in into one (domain1.com) when i visit the domain2.com i'm not logged in.
I know that is a domain cookie problem, but there is a way to generate the cookie for a list of domain when i register/log in?

Hope that someone can help me

Comment: Account Sync module seems to be a good fit but I haven't used it on my own yet. http://drupal.org/project/account_sync

Comment: But i have the same db, so sync the data has no sense, the data are alreay syncronized.

Comment: Nobody can help me writing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my module developed for getting a SSO system working with Drupal and Domain Acces.

https://github.com/andreacavattoni/DomainSSO

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to look at [Bakery](http://drupal.org/project/bakery)

Could be of interest: [Stack Exchange Blog: Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) (using HTML5's local storage)

Comment: "Bakery provides a "single sign on" feature for Drupal based sites that are on the same second-level domain"

I have to do it with different primary domain!

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. I think Vineet's second alt answer is probably the best, though I wonder whether something like that could be achieved with web services, for example the "services" module. I've also edited my answer with an interesting blog post from StackExchange regarding this issue!

Answer (score 1):

This is the very good question and have done small research on your question on different ways:

## OAuth:

After reading the documentation and gone through many service providers it is not possible. Oauth service provider gives the consumer key and secret and they check the request coming from the domain and thus if the same oAuth consumer key is used on different domain Names that doesn't work.

## Setting Cookie Multiple domains

Simply, it is not possible to set the cookie without visiting the domain by any means

**Thus, I can say that it is not possible to set cookie or use the same consumer key and secret for multiple domains**

## Alternative ways

1. Use HTML5 Web Storage for storing the information and then accessing
   the information from different domains is possible.
2. Use AJAX/CURL for sending the request for setting the cookie for different domains such as example.com/session_cookie.php?info=xxxxx
3. Maintain a single sub-domain/page for all the domain for login purpose for across all the domains.

Comment: the (2) seems to be the best way, but i have to build a session_cooke.php, can someone help me for this?
I'm lookign into session.inc but there is no way to start a session and write cookie and stuff

Comment: I can do that Job for you setting and accessing cookies

Comment: I'm writing some code, in your opinion what shall i do?
i've tryed to login trow curl with a key(generate during the login in the first domain), but it doesnt work, maybe cause the cookie...

Comment: Finally i solved, logging in users throw ajax, as Vineet Said.

Comment: @Dtnand That's great thing you have achieved the same. If possible post post in github or other website and share link here also. It must help others also..